Reorder points in vector according to their proximity to the points in another vector
I have two vectors of points in 2D/3D space:
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> points_to_sort;
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> reference_points;
assert(points_to_sort.size() == reference_points.size());

reference_points have some good properties for my task - they are distributed quasi-uniformly, and each subsequent point is "far away" (in terms of distance and angle) from the previous one.
In a naive approach, I would iterate throw reference_points and for each point p in reference_points would find closest point p_c in points_to_sort, mark p_c as visited and pushed p_c in some result container.
This approach is simple, but not exactly fast, and it lacks parallelization (since the same point from reference_points may be the closest for several points from points_to_sort, it's not hard but annoying to handle). It canb e accelerated by using a bounding volume hierarch or octree to speed up the search for the nearest point, but that's all I could come up with.
In fact, you can do look at this without vector reference_points. I want to do something opposite to morton/hilbert curve sort (which can be well parallelized). In these sorts, relatively close points are next to each other, but I want relatively distant points to be next to each other.
So, maybe someone has faced such a problem or have any ideas?

So you want to sort the points by distance from any of the reference points? Is that what you do? Why not make a KD tree out of the reference points? It's just some sorting, which can be parallelized with repeated calls to the parallelized version of std::nth_element. Then just do some parallelized search for nearest neighbor and sort that result

@Homer512, I want to map points from one vector to another. Took first reference point, found closest and pushed to answer vector. Took second reference point, found closest (except first one found), pushed to answer and so on.

boost's spatial indices allow removing points with rebalancing. Seeing how your algorithm has a built-in bias (the first reference point gets the best pick, the last has no choice at all), you cannot really parallelize the search. That is, unless you want something else like minimizing the sum of distances between mapped points
